# Table of pointers cast C++

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

I have this table variable:

```
/// Place all your sensors in this table 
static DetectionSensor *DetectionSensors[] = {
      &Sensor200BP203,
      &SensorXXXX,
}
```

I pass it to a method:

```
DetectionThread.create((void*)DetectionSensors);
```

And in my DetectionThread I have this member:

```
private :
        DetectionSensor *pDetectionSensors[];
```

In a DetectionThread's method I want to cast my argument like that:

```
void Detection::setup()
{
    *this->pDetectionSensors = ((DetectionSensor *)this->parameters);
}
```

When I execute my program, I have an error ...

Comment: You don't allocate memory for `pDetectionSensors`, so you cannot use `*pDetectionSensors`.

Comment: You are not careful with the casts. This will bite you. You are casting `DetectionSensor**` to `void*` but casting back to `DetectionSensor*`.

Comment: "I have an error" Brilliant. Totally crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not clear. On the one hand you speak about method `create` On the other hand you show method `setup`. So what is the relation betwenn `create` and `serup`? And what is the type of parameters?

In any case your code shall not be compiled because you may not define incomplete non-static data members. So this definition

```
private :
        DetectionSensor *pDetectionSensors[];
```

is wrong.

Take into account that the type of DetectionSensors when it is passed as an argument by value is

```
DetectionSensor **pDetectionSensors;
```

And you may not assign an address to an array.

Comment: Also `DetectionSensor` magically becomes `Detection`. The question is very unclear. BTW calling that double-pointer variable `DetectionSensors` is _such_ a bad idea...